# Weird CSS Transitions and Scaling Behaviour with Webkit

Tags: google-chrome, css, transition

I'm working on a website which you can see [here](http://cameronsflash.com/misc/sculptor/test.html)

Some weird things happen in Chrome when the window is a certain resolution. For example, if you make the width 943 pixels, and you hover over an image you will see white bars appear next to some images for the duration of the transition as if the images are re-sizing horizontally.

This doesn't happen in Firefox or IE.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

943px - 16px (padding) = 927px

927px * 20% = 185.38333129882813px (in chrome)

185.38333129882813px * 5 = 926,91...

927 - 926,91... = your white bar

This is sub-pixel problem. 
Look on this site: http://tylertate.com/blog/2012/01/05/subpixel-rounding.html

Comment: I think you mean margin, not padding.

Comment: Unaccepted because although this explains where the white pixels come from, it doesn't explain why they occur only during CSS transitions.

If you can edit your answer to explain that I will accept it.